# "В принципе"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "в принципе" в следующих случаях:
"В принципе(,) он ничем не отличался от остальных".
"Да он(,) в принципе(,) не хотел этим заниматься!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если "в принципе" означает "в сущности говоря, по сути говоря", то это вводное выражение, выделяющеся знаками препинания (обычно запятыми).

Если "в принципе" означает "в основном, в целом", то это обстоятельство. не требующее постановки знаков препинания.

В первом предложении возможны оба варианта; во втором — явно вводное выражение; запятые нужны.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, во втором предложении возможны варианты в зависимости от контекста или от интонации:
а) "Да он, в принципе, не хотел этим заниматься!" (в сущности говоря);
б) "Да он в принципе не хотел этим заниматься!" (вообще, совсем).